# PHP - setcookie() is not working when called per axios request

Tags: php, reactjs, cookies, axios

I am currently developing a web application using PHP as my backend (with mySQL) and React in the frontend. To handle user authorization and authentication, I use JWT. To relogin the user automatically, if he still has a valid token, I want to store the JWT in a Cookie. However, the cookie is not set, when I call it per axios from my React app.

My (demo) code (PHP) (http://localhost/rest/userService.php):

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization');
include('./config/config.php');

if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
  setcookie('jwt', 'test', time() + 1800, '/');
  include('./config/jwt.php');
  echo login($con, json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
}

?>
```

Everything is working fine, I get a valid token back. However, when I look in the Cookies in my F12 tools, no Cookie was set. If I call the function directly in the browser per

```
http://localhost/rest/userService.php?login
```

The cookie gets set and I also see it in my Cookies tab in the F12 tools.

Any suggestions why it does not work with axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve it myself. I added the following header to my .php file:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');`

and added the following to my axios config:

```
withCredentials: true
```